# Minimum possible average in an under-specified set of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

The set $S$ consists of distinct integers such that the smallest is $0$ and the largest is $2015$. What is the minimum possible average (integer) value of the numbers in $S$? (AMC Senior, 2015)

Comment: What have you tried ?  HInt:  there's no point having a "gap" at the lower numbers.  That is, the optimal selection shouldn't look like $(0,1,2,5,2015)$ as you can can clearly do better by replacing the $5$ with a $3$.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I forgot to include something in the question because it's implied by the answer booklet that the value must be an integer. I'll change it now

Comment: As it happens, that doesn't change anything...the answer you get by ignoring that constraint happens to be an integer.  That is fortunate...it would be a difficult constraint to embed in the calculation.

Comment: @lulu I'm getting a non integer. Let me delete my post and try to see my error.

Comment: @lulu I think I see my mistake, editing.

Comment: @Deepak  Well, my method is the same as yours (unsurprisingly).  To minimize it I just computed all  the values and looked at the table. I get the same values for $n$ that you do.   It is, of course, possible that my code has a bug.

Comment: @lulu Finally finished my edits, I kept making silly mistakes - health not a 100% at the moment. :( I think the answer of $62$ is right, but I'm less than satisfied with my method, honestly.

Comment: @Deepak I got $62$, and that was from the fact that the absolute minimum was $61.998...$ (regardless of whether the number was an integer or not), and then the closest integer as $62$. All was left was to show that $62$ was achievable.

Answer (score 4):

Since they are all distinct, and you're aiming for the smallest possible average of the whole set, start "populating" with consecutive positive integers $1, 2, ..., n$

Then the average value will be $\frac{\frac 12 n(n+1) + 2015}{n+2} = \frac 12(n-1+\frac{4032}{n+2})$

Minimising the last expression (I used basic calculus), you get $n \approx 61.498$ as a minimising value.

You know that $n$ needs to be close to that value. The prime factorisation of $4032$ is $(2^6)(3^2)(7)$, and rearranging gives $4032 = (63)(64)$

Hence to give an integer minimal average, you need either $n+2 = 63$ (hence $n=61$) or $n+2 = 64$ (hence $n=62$). Either option gives you a minimum average of $62$.

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot to clarify that the average has to be an integer, since it's implied by the competition answer booklet.

Comment: My numerical method also gets $62$ as the average (+1).  Not sure why you need the bit about factoring $4032$.  You already showed that the answer to the continuous problem is about $n=61.5$ hence the integer solution should be $61$ or $62$.

Comment: Because to get an integer value you need that rational term to be an integer. That's why I had to factor $4032$ into two factors close to the value of $n+2$ corresponding to the minimising $n$ value in the continuous version. I suppose I could just have tried out those two values. I'm not sure if I'm adding any rigour here.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you are.  In integer problems like this you eventually need to search near the continuous solution.  To be clear, had the integer values of $n$ near $61.5$ not returned integer averages the problem gets very hard.  For all we know, the best integer average might be realized by adding a gap or gaps at the base.

Comment: @lulu But suppose that had actually been the case. The continuous problem minimum led one to try $61$ and $62$ but neither was an integer. Now let's say the factorisation was something like $(59)(67)$. Doesn't that mean that we can now "zero in" on $n=57$ and $n=65$ and see which gives a lower average? The factorisation let's us know exactly which two values are worth trying, and because the average function is a "nice" one,  we expect one of these to give the correct minimum integer average. Of course, if the factorisation gave factors far away from $61$ and $62$, all bets are off, I suppose.

Comment: @lulu I guess your point about the possibility of needing a gap at the bottom still stands.

Comment: The optimal continuous average is between $61$ and $62$, as shown by your calculation.  Thus $61$ is not an achievable average.  $62$ is the theoretical minimum for an integer average.  As we achieve $62$ we know we have the result.  To be sure, we have not shown uniqueness.  There might be some other integer way to get to $62$.  But $62$ is optimal.

Comment: @lulu Fair enough, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the reason why you calculated the average dividing by $n+2$. As far as I can see the numbers are $n+1$

Comment: @Raffaele Order from smallest to largest. First is $0$, last is $2015$. You're adding another $n$ numbers from $1..n$ between these two. So total $n+2$.